# C++ unordered_map operator[ ] vs unordered_map.find() performance

Tags: c++, hashmap, time-complexity, unordered-map

I was solving a competitive programming problem on interviewbit.com
I basically used a unordered_map to keep track of visited numbers. When I used operator[], my code could not perform in time, but it passes all tests when I used find. Both should have same time complexity.

I tried timing both codes using clock() by running them 10 times and averaging out the run times and they both gave more or less same time. I used g++ 7.4.0 while the environment provided by website has g++ 4.8.4. Could this be the reason for this.

```cpp
int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A) {
    unordered_map<long long, int> hashmap;
    for(auto a : A)
        hashmap[a] = 1;
    int res = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < A.size(); ++j){
          // if(hashmap.find((long long)A[i] + A[j]) != hashmap.end())
            if(hashmap[(long long)A[i] + A[j]] == 1)
                ++res;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

The problem was to find pairs in array whose sum also exist in the array. I got "time limit exceeded" on array size of about 900 when I used the [] operator.

Comment: `unordered_set` was the right data structure for this solution to the problem.

Comment: Is the input array guaranteed to be in any sort of order? Are negative values allowed?

Comment: @Omnifarious There's no real pattern and negative values may be there. The constraints aren't made clear but an O(n^2) algo should pass.

Comment: Out of random curiosity, I came up with a somewhat different way of solving it involving sorting the values that is also n^2 complexity, but with a much lower multiplier. Mostly it works really hard to limit the ranges in which it looks for answers. It assumes there are no duplicate values. You can find them here: https://godbolt.org/z/JeLsOQ

Comment: @Omnifarious Sorry I didn't understand it at first, and then it was just left at back burner till now. This approach seems similar to 2-pointers approach. Would this approach be preferred in practical cases to the one that I used?

Comment: I wouldn't prefer it, except in cases where it turned out to be very performance sensitive. The main problem with it is that the way it works is significantly less obvious, and it's 'fiddly', lots of moving parts. And that's always bad, absent a really good reason. This problem nags me though. I feel like there must be an n log n solution to it that will be obvious and elegant once someone actually sees it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons why the []-operator will be slower than find:

1. The []-operator calls a non-const function on the map properly preventing all kinds of optimizations, like loop unrolling.
2. The more import reason: The []-operator creates non-existing elements in the map with their default value. The map will be bloated with all pairs of A[i] + A[j], that were not previously in the map and set their values to 0. This will increase the map size and thus the time.

I think your performance measurements showed no difference between the two alternatives because of one or more of this reasons:

1. The input vector is too small to make a difference
2. Most combinations of A[i] + A[j] are already in the vector, so the unordered_map is not bloated enough to make a difference
3. You did not optimize your code (-O3 or -Os) your code

Comment: I used the same test case that failed on the platform. I think my measurements didn't show any significant difference because I didn't optimize it. I can't optimize using o2 or o3 on my system for some reason. I'll update this comment with results once I fix the problem. Thank you

Comment: With O3 optimization, `unordered_map.find()` is about 6 times faster than `unordered_map.at()`